# Finding the limit of a quotient of hazard functions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, hazard

Let $\lambda_i(t),S_i(t)$ be the hazard and survival functions of two populations for $i=1,2$ and satisfy that: $\frac{S_2(t)}{1-S_2(t)}=\phi\frac{S_1(t)}{1-S_1(t)}$ (1) I want to proof that $\lim_{t\to\infty }\frac{\lambda_2(t)}{\lambda_1(t)}=1$

Using that $\lambda(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$ where $f(·)$ is a pdf and $F(·)$ their cdf and the fact that (1) can be expressed as $\frac{1-F_2(t)}{F_2(t)}=\phi\frac{1-F_1(t)}{F_1(t)}$ then:
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\left [ \frac{f_2(t)}{1-F_2(t)}\div \frac{f_1(t)}{1-F_1(t)} \right ]=\lim_{t \to \infty}\left [ \frac{f_2(t)}{\frac{\phi (1-F_1(t))F_2(t)}{F_1(t)}}\div \frac{f_1(t)}{1-F_1(t)} \right ]=\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{f_2(t)F_1(t)}{\phi F_2(t)f_1(t)}=\frac{1}{\phi}\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{f_2(t)}{f_1(t)}$$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @whuber how to prove that the limit tends to 1.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Perhaps you might be able to show $$\lambda_2/\lambda_1=(1-S_2)/(1-S_1)$$ and go on from there.  One approach is through the expressions $$\lambda_i = -\frac{d}{dt}\log S_i(t).$$

Comment: @whuber Thank you, So this means that the limit of the quotient doesn't need to satifsfy the condition (1).

Comment: If you solved this you can answer the Q yourself! Please do so!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I already tried it, and with the info we have it can only be deduced that the limit of $\phi$ tends to 1 and that the limit of the hazard function quotient depends on the density functions that we do not know anything about its limit since it depends on the family.